# How to implement slide between screens with compose NavHost like viewPager2

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewpager2

I have an app with bottom navigation bar and navHost, and I want the ability to slide to the sides to go to the screen next by.
I was able to do this with viewPager2 and fragments, but i NavHost I couldn't find any similar feature.

Maybe track the user input to listen for sliding motion and change the current screen?